# How can we use Windows Azure Scheduler to invoke a web service of Sharepoint Online?

Tags: azure, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have a requirement where I have to do some action on SharePoint online in regular intervals. As there is no option of timer jobs on SharePoint online, so how can we use Windows Azure Scheduler to trigger a web service of SharePoint online on regular intervals.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the process you want to run you can leverage the "Pause for Duration" or "Pause Until Date" actions in the native Workflow engine in SharePoint to achieve a similar.  Works in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

As Simon W said, using the Workflow engine is the best.

You can't use Windows Azure Scheduler since it needs an endpoint that it can call with no authentication and you wouldn't be able to do that with SharePoint Online.